# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modal')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I'm trying to install `@mui/x-date-pickers` to my project and I followed the instructions from their website, which you can find [here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/). The problem is when i installed everything and added this code to my project

```
import React from 'react';
import { LocalizationProvider, TimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { AdapterMoment } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment';
import moment from 'moment';

export const Blabla = () => {
   const [value, setValue] = React.useState(moment('2014-08-18T21:11:54'));

   const handleChange = (newValue: any) => {
      setValue(newValue);
   };
   return (
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterMoment}>
         <TimePicker
            label="Time"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
         />
       </LocalizationProvider>
    );
};
```

I am getting this error
[image]

And this is how my dependencies look like in the `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
  "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.11",
  "auth0-js": "^9.13.2",
  "axios": "^0.19.2",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "6",
  "crossfilter": "^1.3.12",
  "crossfilter2": "^1.5.4",
  "cubejs": "^1.3.2",
  "d3": "^6.2.0",
  "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
  "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
  "emotion": "^10.0.27",
  "emotion-theming": "^10.0.27",
  "highcharts": "8.1.2",
  "highcharts-custom-events": "3.0.9",
  "highcharts-react-official": "3.0.0",
  "html-to-image": "^1.10.8",
  "i18next": "^19.4.4",
  "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
  "json2mq": "^0.2.0",
  "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
  "jsverify": "^0.8.4",
  "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
  "mixpanel-browser": "2.41.0",
  "moment": "^2.25.3",
  "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
  "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
  "ramda": "^0.27.0",
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
  "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
  "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
  "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
  "react-datetime": "^3.0.4",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dropzone": "^12.0.1",
  "react-email-editor": "^1.2.0",
  "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.21",
  "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
  "react-i18next": "^11.4.0",
  "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^5.1.0",
  "react-leaflet": "^2.7.0",
  "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.11",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-slick": "^0.26.1",
  "react-tooltip": "^4.2.11",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
  "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
  "topojson-client": "^3.1.0",
  "urlencode": "^1.1.0",
  "webpack": "^4.42.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
  "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.9.4",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5",
  "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.9.0",
  "@cubejs-client/core": "^0.25.0",
  "@date-io/moment": "^2.16.1",
  "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.7.2",
  "@emotion/core": "10.1.1",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
  "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.27",
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.11",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
  "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.53",
  "@mui/material": "^5.11.1",
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.18",
  "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.2.1",
  "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.18",
  "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.3.18",
  "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.18",
  "@storybook/react": "^5.3.18",
  "@svgr/webpack": "^5.3.1",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.5.0",
  "@testing-library/react": "^10.0.4",
  "@types/auth0-js": "^9.12.4",
  "@types/d3": "^5.16.3",
  "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.7",
  "@types/jest": "25.2.1",
  "@types/json2mq": "^0.2.0",
  "@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
  "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.17",
  "@types/lodash": "4.14.151",
  "@types/mixpanel-browser": "2.35.6",
  "@types/node": "^17.0.17",
  "@types/papaparse": "^5.2.5",
  "@types/ramda": "0.27.6",
  "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
  "@types/react-codemirror": "^1.0.3",
  "@types/react-copy-to-clipboard": "^4.3.0",
  "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.1",
  "@types/react-dates": "^17.1.10",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
  "@types/react-email-editor": "^1.1.1",
  "@types/react-leaflet": "^2.5.2",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
  "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
  "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.0.1",
  "@types/urlencode": "^1.1.2",
  "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.3",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.33.1",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
  "autoprefixer": "^9.7.6",
  "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  "babel-plugin-emotion": "^10.0.33",
  "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
  "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
  "eslint": "7.1.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.1",
  "eslint-import-resolver-jest": "3.0.0",
  "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.12.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "2.21.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.0.2",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.1",
  "husky": "^7.0.4",
  "jest": "25.2.1",
  "jest-emotion": "^10.0.32",
  "lint-staged": "^10.1.6",
  "npx": "^10.2.2",
  "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
  "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1",
  "storybook-addon-emotion-theme": "^2.1.1",
  "storybook-addon-jsx": "^7.2.3",
  "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
  "ts-jest": "^25.4.0",
  "typescript": "4.6",
  "typescript-styled-plugin": "^0.15.0",
  "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
},
```

What am I doing wrong?